# Это люстра или лампа (на фото, см.)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чем является этот светильник: люстрой или лампой?

Можно ли по отношению к люстре употреблять слово "светильник"?

Answer (score 3):

Это потолочный светильник-плафон, т. е. накладной в отличие от подвесных светильников и люстр, создающих почти бестеневое освещение (в отличие от точечных источников света).